# What does 3523 fail mean in Teradata?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, macros, teradata

I am trying to pass a column name of a table into a stored procedure so as to produce quantiles (min,25th,50th,75th percentiles,max). Create procedure was successfull. But when I execute call I am getting an owner referenced error.
Below is my code:

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE (IN COL CHAR(50))
BEGIN 

INSERT INTO PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE_5

SELECT 
'ACPT_'||:COL AS VAR,
MIN(:COL) AS PER_MIN,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_25,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_50,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_75,
MAX(:COL) AS PER_MAX
FROM (
SELECT PC.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY :COL) AS SEQNUM,
COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.ACPT_PROD_CVM PC
WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2016-10-18'
)A
GROUP BY 1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
'PROD_'||:COL AS VAR,
MIN(:COL) AS PER_MIN,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.25 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_25,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.50 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_50,
MIN(CASE WHEN SEQNUM / 0.75 >= CNT THEN :COL END) AS PER_75,
MAX(:COL) AS PER_MAX
FROM (
SELECT PC.*,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY :COL) AS SEQNUM,
COUNT(*) OVER () AS CNT
FROM PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.PROD_CVM PC
WHERE PC.PW_END_DATE =  '2016-10-18'
)B
GROUP BY 1
;

CALL PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE('DURATION_MACRO_CURR');
```

Desired result:

[image]

To me it looks like I have to approach DBA for this?

Following is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Do you have permission to run those statements when you run them outside the stored proc?  If so then the issue is probably that PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE needs to be granted SELECT permission on PROD_EXP_DL_CVM.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. Yes I was able to get the attached desired result by substituting parameters with one intended variable.

Comment: Try changing the security to `INVOKER`: REPLACE PROCEDURE PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE (IN COL CHAR(50)) SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN`. Btw, you don't need a SP for this, a simple Macro can do that, too.

Comment: Hi Dieter. Can we really pass a column as a parameter to a macro? I read somewhere in the forum that we can't.
http://community.teradata.com/t5/UDA/How-to-create-a-Macro-passing-table-names-as-the-parameter/td-p/7590

Comment: After introducing INVOKER, I am getting error 2620: The format or data contains a bad character. Can it be coming from how I am passing the column_name? here:  `'ACPT_'||:COL AS VAR,` or `CALL PROD_CE_WORK_SPACE.NPVAZ_CVM_CHECK_TEST_CASE('DURATION_MACRO_CURR');`

Comment: Ups, of course you can't pass a column name to a macro, but that's the same for a SP. You need to use Dynamic SQL, i.e. construct a SQL-string and then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.